# npm install works in WebStorm terminal, fails in cmd (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, cmd, npm, webstorm, npm-install

So I'm using Angular 2. I'm trying to start using this boilerplate (although the problem exists with any other as well): https://github.com/preboot/angular2-webpack

When I use `npm install` in the WebStorm's terminal everything works just fine.

However, when I used the same command in the cmd it won't install devDependencies (will do so if I force `npm install --only=dev`). Also when I try to run `npm start` it works fine if I installed in WebStorm but not if I installed through cmd.

Errors when installing through cmd are mostly "modules not found". For example:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
(1,26): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
```

Are there any logs or similar that I can provide?

Comment: Try with this: `$ rm -rf node_modules dist tmp && npm install`

Comment: @narainsagar Tried this but doesn't help anything. Literally just a new git clone and npm install won't work properly in cmd, while it will in webstorm